# Ruby string include? percent sign include? '%' (Rubymine debugger)

Tags: ruby

**This is due to something in the watches section of the RubyMine debugger.  IRB works fine**

I'm mystified.  I cannot figure out how to see if a ruby string includes a `%` sign.

I've tried:

```
text = "Foo %{bar}"

text.include? '%'
text.include? '\%'
text.include? '%%'
```

...as well as with double quotes.  I've also tried the regex equivalents.  I'm sure it is something incredibly simple but this isn't something easily found through a search due to the normal use of the symbol.

**Not a problem now that it has been identified as the IDE.  Vote to close. Thank you**

Comment: Works fine for me...`text = "Foo %{bar}" ; text.include? '%' => true`

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? Are you running this at the command-line or inside an IDE?

Comment: Sorry, IRB is just fine.  I was debugging a bigger section of code and the watch values in RubyMine were erroring.  My fault for not attempting it in IRB first.

Comment: While IDEs are nice, there comes a point where they get in the way. This is such a point. I've given up on them and only use text editors (vim and Sublime Text), IRB/Pry and a good debugger. I don't want anything to give me confusing results like you're seeing. Coding is difficult enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see what the problem is when using `include? '%'`:

```
text = "Foo %{bar}"

text.include? '%'  # => true
text.include? '\%' # => false
text.include? '%%' # => false
```

You can also use the String [`[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) shortcuts:

```
text['%'] # => "%"
!!text['%'] # => true
```

Comment: nice, didn't know about those shortcuts

Comment: See the String [`[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) documentation.